# regexp replace with function wrong result in javascript

Tags: javascript

See below code:

```
'fontSize'.replace(/(.?)([A-Z])/g, function (m, p, z) {
    return p == '\\' ? z : p + '-' + z.toLowerCase()
})
```

It's replace S with `-s`, but for input `fontSBCize` the result will be `font-sB-cize`, the even number upper letter always not changed.

What's wrong here? Any solution for this problem?

In brief, the result test case:

test passed: `fontSBCize` => `font-s-b-cize`

test passed: `font\\S\\B\\Cize` => `fontSBCize`

test passed: `font\\SBCize` => `fontS-b-cize`

Comment: What do you want as a result for "fontSBCize"->"font-sbcize"?

Comment: @rparree, please see the updated test case above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to convert camelCase to snake-case use this (it supports escaping chars):

```
str.replace(/\\?([A-Z])/g, function($0, $1) {
    return $1 === $0 ? "-"+$1.toLowerCase() : $1;
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
console.log('font\\SBCsize'.replace(/\\?([A-Z])/g, function($0, $1) {
  return $1 === $0 ? "-"+$1.toLowerCase() : $1;
}))

console.log('font\\S\\B\\Csize'.replace(/\\?([A-Z])/g, function($0, $1) {
  return $1 === $0 ? "-"+$1.toLowerCase() : $1;
}))

console.log('fontSBCsize'.replace(/\\?([A-Z])/g, function($0, $1) {
  return $1 === $0 ? "-"+$1.toLowerCase() : $1;
}))
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, please see the test case above, the need is also have ability to **escape** the replace, using `\\` in javascript string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to account for escape character (check its character code which is 92)

```js
function replacer(input) {
  return input.replace(/[\\]*[A-Z]/g, function(m) {
    return m.charCodeAt() != 92 ? "-" + m.toLowerCase() : m.substring(1);
  });
}

console.log( replacer( "fontSBCize" ) );
console.log( replacer( "font\\S\\B\\Cize" ) );
console.log( replacer( "font\\SBCize" ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I've found the solution below that can passed the test case:

```
'fontSDCize'.replace(/(.?)([A-Z])/g, function (m, p, z) {
    return p == '\\' 
    ? z 
    : (/[A-Z]/.test(p) ? '-'+p.toLowerCase() : p) + '-' + z.toLowerCase()
})
```

Maybe there's any better way? Improvement welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You could split the string and process every character.

```js
function replace(s) {
    return s.split('').map(function (a, i, aa) {
        return a === '\\' ?
            '' :
            aa[i - 1] === '\\' || a === a.toLowerCase() ?
                a :
                '-' + a.toLowerCase();
    }).join('');
}

console.log(replace('fontSize'));
console.log(replace('fontSBCize'));
console.log(replace('font\\S\\B\\Cize'));
console.log(replace('font\\SBCize'));
```